# fs.watchFile delayed nodejs

Tags: node.js, file

If you run the following script I run into the issue that the script doesn't run on every 1sec update but less frequent like every 3-5 seconds.  Is this a bug of node.js or is there a way to fix it?

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var f = "C:\\Test.txt";
fs.watchFile(f, (curr, prev) => {
  console.log(`the current mtime is: ${curr.mtime} ${prev.mtime}`);
  console.log(String(fs.readFileSync(f)));
});

setInterval(function() {
  fs.writeFileSync('C:\\Test.txt',String(Date.now()));
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is writing correctly on `setInterval` but `fs.watchFile` polls at its own interval. You can set the polling interval with the options parameter:

```
fs.watchFile(f, {interval: 1000}, (curr, prev) => {
    ...
}
```

This should work more like you expect.

Comment: Would it be bad to set this to 100 milliseconds?

Comment: I'm really not sure. It works okay here, but there's no load.

Answer (score 0):

```js
fs.watchFile(f, {interval: 2000}, (curr, prev) => {
  console.log(`the current mtime is: ${curr.mtime} ${prev.mtime}`);
  console.log(String(fs.readFileSync(f)));
});
```

will check file every 2 seconds, default appears to be 5.